# OutputStreamWriter java can't store into string

Tags: java, utf-8, filestreamresult

```
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out, "UTF-8")));
```

I'm using this to generate the output to console. I want to store the output to a sting. I don't know how to do. Can any one help me? :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example use this (it avoids encoding the string):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
String str = writer.getBuffer().toString();
```

Comment: `toString()` of `StringWriter` already goes to the buffer so: `String str = writer.toString();`

Answer (score 2):

Use `StringWriter` class instead of `OutputStreamWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could look like this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc),new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")));
String string = new String(out.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```